# Set textbox value when another change in a listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding

I have an ObservableCollection containing Hour (object). Inside, I have a Title and a Value properties.

On my view, I have a listview, binding on this collection. Title is a textblock, Value is a textbox (user can input text).

I would like to change the content of all textbox (value) when one change.
A litle bit of code :

```
public class Hour : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        private int valueContent;
        public int Value
        {
            get { return valueContent; }
            set 
            {
                valueContent = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }
}
```

my observablecollection :

```
private ObservableCollection<Hour> hours;
public ObservableCollection<Hour> Hours
{
    get { return hours; }
    set
    {
        hours= value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Hours");
    }
}
```

xaml :

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Hours, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedHour,Mode=TwoWay}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HourTemplate}" />
<DataTemplate x:Key="HourTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="18" Width="150" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="15" Width="150" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

So, I will have for example :

```
Title           -          Value
08h00           -           0
09h00           -           0
10h00           -           0
11h00           -           0
12h00           -           0
```

I would like, when I change one value (e.g: 10h00), all value after this one change to the value of 10h00.
Here the result expected :

```
Title           -          Value
08h00           -           0
09h00           -           0
10h00           -           1 <--- change here
11h00           -           1 <--- change because 10h00 changed
12h00           -           1 <--- change because 10h00 changed
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any *clean* way to do this.

I would start by adding an event to the `Hour` class, `ValueUpdated`. Raise that event in the setter for `Value` and have the view model listen to it *for* every `Hour` object. Have the event pass the sender as a parameter, something like:

```
public event Action<Hour> ValueUpdated;

//When raising
var handler = ValueUpdated;
if (handler != null)
   handler(this);
```

Now in the view model handler, you need to find the index of the sender, then apply the change to every hour after it.

```
private void HandleValueUpdate(Hour sender)
{
   int senderIndex = allItems.IndexOf(sender);
   IEnumerable<Hour> subsequentHours = allItems.Skip(senderIndex + 1);

   foreach (Hour h in subsequentHours)
   {
       h.SetValue(sender.Value);
   }
}
```

You'll probably want to make a way of doing that set *without* raising the `ValueUpdated` event, as this won't be very efficent if you do. I modeled that by calling a function instead of setting the property, but how you do it is up to you.

Comment: Thanks mate ! I had an infinity loop, just needed to check when Value is set, if it wasn't already updated. but now it works.

Comment: @carndacier Yeah, if you just set the property, you'll end up with a *lot* of extra function calls. Glad you got it working!